# Succesive bissection method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

> Suppose that for a given function $\mathrm{f}$ that has three roots $\mathrm{r_1}<\mathrm{r_2}<\mathrm{r_3}$ in an interval $\mathrm{[a,b]}$. Which one of the roots would be determined if the bissection method is applied to the interval [a,b]?

I can't find any particular pattern when I think of a function with these particular restraints. Is there something to be noticed?

Comment: It will greatly depend on where the roots lie. EG Can you consider the cases of $ a < r_1 < r_2 < (a+b)/2 < r_3 < b$ and $ a < r_1 < (a+b)/2 < r_2 < r_3 < b$? which root would we find?